# @MapKey breaks with hibernate version 4.3.9 onwards. It works fine with 4.3.8

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We have the below entity mapping in our project. It is working fine until hibernate version 4.3.8 but when i upgrade to 4.3.11, the test cases started failing with the below error.

### Entity mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee 
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @MapKey(name = "phoneType")
  private Map<PhoneType, Phone> phones = new HashMap<PhoneType, Phone>()

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PHONE")
public class Phone 
{
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
  @NotNull
  private Employee owner;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
  @NotNull
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private PhoneType phoneType;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
  private String phoneNumber;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PHONE_TYPE")
public class PhoneType 
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "PHONE_TYPE_ID")
  private long id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "PHONE_TYPE")
  private String phoneType;

  ...
}
```

---

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate collection index join within collection join [ : OneToManyPersister(com.xyz.Employee.phones)]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.renderCollectionJoin(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.renderJoin(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.processQuerySpaceJoin(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.processQuerySpaceJoins(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.processQuerySpaceJoins(LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadQueryDetails.generate(AbstractLoadQueryDetails.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails.(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.makeEntityLoadQueryDetails(BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader.(EntityLoader.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader.(EntityLoader.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader$Builder.byUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader$Builder.byPrimaryKey(EntityLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.buildNonBatchingLoader(AbstractBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.BatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.buildLoader(BatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2528)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4035)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4017)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 44 more

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod springTestContextBeforeTestMethod
SKIPPED: testPhone

Comment: Have you found solution for this problem in meantime? Even workaround is ok. I have similar case and exception :|

Comment: Did you try this with `FetchType.LAZY` for the map association? I.e.: `@OneToMany(mappedBy="owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`? For me it seems to make the difference between successful mapping and the exception you got.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete that only works until something in your application tries to fetch the lazy loaded objects. You are just delaying the failure with lazy load.

Comment: @DavidR too much time passed, I can't reflect on that anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [@MapKeyJoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html) if the key is an entity.

Comment: @MapKeyJoinColumn is creating un-necessary db updates. Please see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804910/mapkeyjoincolumn-is-creating-un-necessary-db-update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804910/mapkeyjoincolumn-is-creating-un-necessary-db-update)